# Adobe Air application automatically crashes after splash screen on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have built my first Adobe Air application. The app automatically crashes after i try to run it from my iPhone, it just flashes a black screen and crashes.

It's working more than fine if i switch to Adobe Air 3.2 for Android and test it on an actual device, but whenever i try to test it on an iOS device, it just automatically crashes! I have created the `.p12` certificate, and the distribution profile as i should.

I am Using Adobe Flash CS6, and Adobe Air 3.2 for iOS. My iPhone is on iOS 9.3.3. 
I really have no idea what to do, what can i do in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was just in front of my eyes, u need to download the newest SDK ! i had the 3.2, and now the current version is 22. As soon as i added it, and run the application, it worked like a charm.